# onclick not working for dynamically created button .. how to solve this in this particular case?

Tags: javascript, onclick

On click is not working for this dynamically created button that is supposed to show a pop-up window once clicked on , how can I do this in this particular case by solving this inline ..

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">
    <img src="includes/languages/english/images/buttons/button_select.gif"
       border="0" alt="Select" title=" Select " 
       onclick="popupWindowSelectImg(\'./images_select.php?imgSize=thumb&inpt=products_image_sm_1&div=div_img_sm1&width=200&height=30\',"thumb","products_image_sm_1","div_img_sm1");"/>
</a>
```

Comment: I don't see any jQuery in your question - are you using it at all?

Comment: I can't believe I'm suggesting this, but you can string commands together as long as you end them with a semicolon: `<a href="#" onclick='popupWindowSelectImg(\'./images_select.php?imgSize=thumb&inpt=products_image_sm_1&div=div_img_sm1&width=200&height=30\',"thumb","products_image_sm_1","div_img_sm1"); return false;'>`

Comment: I'd like to do this without Jquery .. is this possible ?

Comment: If you are a person who likes the MVC, its nice to separate Markup from Events/Code.  :)  Given that, what happens when you remove the "onclick" from the anchor tag?

Comment: I did it with Jquery guys , thanks .. I was hoping to do this without Jquery

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">
<img src="includes/languages/english/images/buttons/button_select.gif"
   border="0" alt="Select" title=" Select " 
   onclick="popupWindowSelectImg('images_select.php?imgSize=thumb&inpt=products_image_sm_1&div=div_img_sm1&width=200&height=30','thumb','products_image_sm_1','div_img_sm1'); return false;"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HdL6u/

Comment: lol I know that , the button was dynamically created and appended by Jquery .. thanks though